# setInterval doesn't work, what might be wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

i'm creating a count down time, and here is my piece of code, but it just doesn't work, what might i be doing wrong?

```
<div id="container">
    <h1 id="time">0:00</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var minutes = 1;
        var secondsRemaining = minutes * 60;
        intervalHandle = setInterval(tick,1000);
        function tick(){
            var timeDisplay = $('#time');
            var min = Math.floor(secondsRemaining / 60);
            var sec = secondsRemaining - (min * 60);
            if(sec < 0){
                sec = "0" + sec;
            }
            var message = min.toString() + ":" + sec;
            timeDisplay.html(message);
            if(secondsRemaining === 0){
                alert('Done!');
                clearInterval(intervalHandle);
                resetPage();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

`

Comment: What debugging have you done? What were the results?

Comment: Time to start debugging. Strip the code down to its essentials and use console.log or alert to figure out where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to decrease the seconds each step :-) they are still equal to 60:

```
secondsRemaining--;
```

Here's fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/GhnMr/